# Convert JsonResult to ViewResult in Filter with ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, controller, action-filter, jsonresult, viewresult

My task is to make sure that a controller can return a Json-like response or a View based on who calls the corresponding API.
To do that, I changed the returns of each controller I made so that they give a **JsonResult** and I created a class that extends **IResultFilter**.

In the **OnResultExecuting** method extended by **IResultFilter** I inserted my implementation: I examine the *Accept* header of the call and if it contains *text/html* I have to convert the **JsonResult** into a **ViewResult**, using as a viewModel only the Json **Value** body (which also contains other information about the call that I don't need in the ViewModel).
But not being in a controller, I can not create a ViewResult object.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In a IResultFilter the Result property is readonly. But it's not the case in IActionFilter. There you can override the Result :

```
public class TestFilter : Attribute, IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var controller = context.Controller as Controller;
        controller.ViewData.Model = ((JsonResult)context.Result).Value;
        context.Result = new ViewResult()
        {
            ViewName = "Test",
            ViewData = controller.ViewData
        };
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {  
    }
}
```

Comment: The Result is editable in the OnResultExecuting and it doesn't in OnResultExecuted.

Anyway, using your method, how can I set ViewName properly? 

Thanks for the answer